# Issue installing gem

Tags: ruby, gem

So I'm trying to install this gem but hitting an error. https://github.com/cgore/ruby-btce The actual README says to do a gem install, so I guess I didn't need to clone the git repo? Anyway, I had to install Ruby before doing this and that's all I've installed so far, so I guess I may be missing some other dependencies to install this gem? Error I am getting when attempting a "gem install btce" is:

```
ERROR:  Error installing btce:
eRROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:13:in <main>
```

Considering it's a gem install and I guess it would be the equivalent of installing something from another package manager, it means that nothing already on my existing file system is required (such as a file... that it appears to be missing).

So my next assumption would be a missing dependency. But is there a way to find what it could be when the error message doesn't say what is missing?

Comment: How did you install `ruby`? Did you use `RVM` or compiled from source? Chances are if you compiled from source, you would need to do `sudo gem install btce`

Comment: I apt-get installed it on debian 7.1. Then proceed to gem install. I suppose I could look into using RVM if you think it could help.

Answer (score 1):

Required to install `ruby-dev` and dependencies.

As per SO post: [`require': no such file to load — mkmf (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7645918/55075).